# Choosing 2 subgroups and pairing them

Tags: combinatorics

Say there are for instance 15 dogs and 20 cats. I want to find the number of options to choose 8 dogs and 8 cats, and pair them - a dog with a cat. I thought about:
$${20 \choose 8}{15 \choose 8}8!$$

but I wonder if that $8!$ is even needed here. After I choose the subgroups, do I indeed have to multiply by the number of pairings that can be done?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary, otherwise you just have a group of eight dogs and eight cats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

${20 \choose 8}\cdot{15 \choose 8}$

you count the number of different subsets you can create out of the 15-element set (of dogs), and one 8-element subset, out of the 20-element set of cats. So, you have a pair of subsets, but you want a subset of pairs *i.e.* pairings of individual cats and dogs, which is a bijection between the subsets.

8! is the number of bijections between two sets of size 8. Hence you multiply by 8!